# Find time difference in days with R

Tags: r, strptime

Does anyone have a clue why in the following code I get "Time difference of NA secs" result? I was expecting to get the difference of days, like the It did for "2015-01-06".

```
today <- Sys.Date()
today <- strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d")
date <- "2015-01-06"
date <- strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
today - date
Time difference of 321 days
```

Well done. But then...

```
date <- "2015-10-18"
date <- strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
today - date
Time difference of NA secs
```

Why secs?

EDIT: Here is session info

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the second one.  I get `today - date#
Time difference of 37 days`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but somehow R is changing unit from days to secs, I think.

Comment: Can It be because of my system time zone? Here in Brazil the standard is "%d-%m-%Y".

Comment: Of course. Your format string has to match your date format.

Comment: It's not so obvious. It should work for "2015-10-18" the same way It did for "2015-01-06", doesn't It?. Besides, `Sys.Date()` returns `2015-11-23` which match my string format.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. If you specify `difftime(today, date, units = "days")` do you get the same result?

Comment: `Time difference of NA days`. I'm gonna edit my question with session info, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with system timezone, although  I can't see any reason to substract "2015-01-06" and "2015-10-18" didn't.