# NA difference in as.difftime R

Tags: r, difftime

It might seem as if it is duplicate of [Find time difference in days with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878552/find-time-difference-in-days-with-r) but I guess it is not.

The problem is simple. I have two time stamps (`format='%H:%M:%S'`):

```
times <- c('02:51:43', '02:45:52')
```

and I want to calculate the time difference, however my attempt results with an unwanted behaviour:

```
as.difftime(times[1], times[2])
# Time difference of NA secs
```

I tried to specify `format` along with the `units='secs'`, but I get the error that the argument `time2` is not used.

Can someone give me a hint where I make a mistake? 
(Sorry in advance, but I ain't even sure if it is reproducible.)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why this post is *not useful, unclear or does not show any research effort* to get down-voted. In fact, it is still unclear for me why `as.difftime` does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `times` into `POSIXct` format and then subtract

```
x1 <- as.POSIXct(times, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
x1[1] - x1[2]

#Time difference of 5.85 mins
```

which is also equivalent to

```
difftime(x1[1], x1[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and I assigned the date-time class to the object again then it worked.

Suppose I have 2 date-time objects:

```
day1<-as.Date('2018-12-31')
day2<-as.Date('2019-12-31')
```

But this 'Time difference of NA secs' occurred, so I simply do this:

```
day1<-as.Date(day1)
day2<-as.Date(day2)
```

Then it worked fine:

```
difftime(day2,day1,units="days")
#Time difference of 365 days
```

Hope this helps.